# Add a correlation or trace ID to Python log calls

Tags: python, logging

Given a complex application in Python that uses standard library logging, something like:

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("mycomponent")

# (Split over multiple Python files/folders of course)

def do_a_really_specific_thing(x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        logger.info("I'm doing a thing! %s", x)
        return 2 * x
    else:
        logger.error("Ignoring non-integer value %s", x)
        return 0

def run_a_task(task_input):
    return do_a_really_specific_thing(task_input.x)

def process_a_transaction(req):
    y = run_a_task(req.data)
    result = y + 1
    logger.info("Processed transaction %s", req.txn_id)
    return result
```

Is there some standard pattern, without editing the code of the inner function `do_a_really_specific_thing()`, to decorate any sandard `logging` events raised within a context with additional information like a trace or correlation ID?

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```py
def process_a_transaction(req):
    with decorate_logs(txn_id=req.txn_id):
        y = run_a_task(req.data)
    return y + 1
```

It seems like a pretty standard idea, but the articles I've come across all seem to involve bringing in some big logging framework or other tools. For e.g. [here with Datadog](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/connect_logs_and_traces/python/), [here with SolarWinds AppOptics](https://documentation.solarwinds.com/en/success_center/appoptics/content/kb/apm_tracing/python/context-log.htm).

Answer (score 0):

This is supported by stdlib logging out of the box and documented in the [logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#adding-contextual-information-to-your-logging-output) (part of the Python documentation). Specifically, you can use a `LoggerAdapter` or a logging filter to impart this type of additional information. The cookbook example relates to peer IP addresses for a network application, but it can be used in the same way for your transaction IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is old, answering this so that others might need it. The below method displays a trace_id along with logs (where **token** is the trace_id)

```
   def info(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):

      frame, filepath, line_number, function_name, lines, index = inspect.stack()[1]
      fileName = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filepath))[0]

      extra = {'token': rid, 'fileName': fileName, 'function_name': function_name}
      logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
      logger.propagate = False
      logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
      consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
      consoleHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
      formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] [%(fileName)s:%(function_name)s() %(levelname)s - %(token)s] %(message)s')
      consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
      if (logger.hasHandlers()):
         logger.handlers.clear()
      logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
      logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra)
      logger.info(msg,*args, **kwargs)
```